# Smarty / Format a number in 5 characters

Tags: smarty, number-formatting

I want to format every variables, with smarty, in a specific character numbers (5).

Example :

```
{foreach from=$products name=product}
{$product.id_product|number_format=-5}
{/foreach}
```

For many reasons, i would like to show the id but in 5 characters like this :

```
1 => 00001
48 => 00048
647 => 00647
4782 => 04782
```

It's possible ? I try |number_format and |string_format, it's not working..

Comment: There's no need to add thanks/solved/solutions in the question here on Stack Overflow - the best way to show an answer solved your issue/helped you is to check the "accept" tick mark next to the answer.

Comment: Ok, sorry , i checked the tick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`string_format`](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.string.format.tpl) which uses [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) this way:

```
{1|string_format:"%05s"}
<br />
{48|string_format:"%05s"}
<br />
{647|string_format:"%05s"}
<br />
{4782|string_format:"%05s"}
```

Comment: Super ! Merci Florian.